# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined node

Tags: javascript, node.js

pardon me for asking such a beginner level question, because I not satisfied with answers titled with same question. Basically I need a promise return type for my function after performing some packages  function which also returns promise.

myquest.js

```
module.exports = somefunction = (data){
  //performs some processing with data
  somePackagePromiseFunc()  //return type promise
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return new Promise.resolve(data);
  }).catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    return new Promise.reject(err);
  });
}
```

mymain.js

```
var somefunction = require('myquest');

somefunction(data).then((data) => {
  console.log('job done with data ' + data);
}).catch(() => {
  console.log('we messed with error: ' + err);
})
```

Help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: some typo edited..

Comment: Maybe you should call `somePackagePromiseFunc` as a function with `()`

Comment: return new Promise.resolve(data); will return a promise from the inner function but not from somefunction, so it will return the default return value i.e. undefined.

Comment: if `somePackagePromiseFunc` is a Promise ... good, but that doesn't mean, if what you were trying to do with that first bit of code is export a function (your syntax is very broken) - that function returns undefined, as there is no return in that function

Comment: also, Promise.reject and Promise.resolve are not constructors, so your code would fail with an error saying so, and `.then` returns a Promise already, so that would be redundant anyway ...

Comment: `somefunction` is missing its arrow, ie `(data) => {`. What is `somePackagePromiseFunc`, a promise or a function that returns a promise?

Comment: Apart from a minor amount of logging, `somefunction` does absolutely nothing. You might as well just directly import `somePackagePromiseFunc`

Comment: thanks all, basically I am trying to move all my logical constrains to separate files so that post and get request looks cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest fix to your code is

1. Fix the syntax in the first line
2. return something, in this case a Promise, in that function
3. is `somePackagePromiseFunc` a function? then call it
4. fix the return value in .then/.catch

You'll end up with

```
module.exports = function (data) {
  //performs some processing with data

  return somePackagePromiseFunc().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }).catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  });
}
```

Note about some of your code:

```
return new Promise.resolve(data);
```

Promise.resolve is not a constructor, so remove `new` would make it

```
return Promise.resolve(data);
```

However, you're inside a .then, whatever you return is a Promise that resolves the the value returned in .then - so, no need to wrap it in Promise.resolve at all - so that's why you only need

```
return data;
```

Similarly for .catch, except to return a rejected promise, you `throw` instead of `return` - though technically you can

```
return Promise.reject(err);
```

Note, no "new", because it's also not a constructor

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried by just returning data and throwing err directly. Still I am getting undefined. I want somefunction to make sure some processing has been completed so that I can proceed with next process.

Comment: in that case, you probably didn't notice the `return` in `return somePackagePromiseFunc().then((data) => {`